# Unable to populate dynamic parameter using active choice plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using the active choices jenkins plugin. I'm trying to populate a drop down list which should contain all the files and directories exist in one of the jenkins master directory.

Below is the groovy code that is listing all the directories and files(checked from "execute system groovy script" jenkins). But the drop down list is not showing any values. I mean the list is empty.

**Code:**

```
new File("/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DATA/workspace/cache_data").eachFileMatch(~/.*.*/)

 { file ->  

    println file.getName()  
}
```

Can someone tell me why the list is appearing empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning an object of the items. Something like:

```
def returnList = []

returnList = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DATA/workspace/cache_data").list()
              .findAll {  it.matches( ~/.*.*/ ) }
              .collect { it } 

return returnList
```

The plugin page https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin also has lots of examples.

Comment: @R.V you made an edit to my response, did it help? If yes, you could  mark it as an accepted answer?